# c++ void* with references within parameter list

Tags: c++, parameters, reference, void-pointers, function-prototypes

```
void printFunc( void(*)(int&,int&), int& );
```

I don't know what this code does. I know it's a function prototype with two parameters, but I don't know what the first parameter means.

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter type is a pointer to a function that takes two arguments, both `int&`s, and returns `void`.

```
void foo(int&, int&);
```

If you have this function declaration, you could pass `foo` as an argument to `printFunc`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pointer to a function which takes two `int&` parameters and returns `void`.

If there was an identifier for it (let's say `p`), it would be spelled like this:

```
void (*p)(int&, int&)
```

Then, we can apply the principle "if we type the declaration as an expression, we get its type." So:

1. `(*p)` means `p` is a pointer
2. `(*p)(int&, int&)` means `(*p)` is a function taking two `int&` parameters
3. `void (*p)(int&, int&)` means it returns `void`.